# Comparing here-API-routes: Are the leg-waypoints the same if parts of the route are the same?

Tags: routes, here-api

I'd like to compare two routes given from here-api on their similarity.

Basically: PersonA has a route from point A to point X, person B from point B to point X. 
So Route A looks like this: 
A-C-D-X
Route B looks like this: 
B-C-D-X

Can I assume that the maneuvres given from a here-api-route from point C to X will be exactly the same?

Do you know any better way to compare those API-given routes than comparing their maneuvres?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Adding **&representation=linkPaging** to your routing query like given below will give you all the links/roads information. Assuming C-D direction of travel for both routes A-C-D-X and B-C-D-X are same the link information for C and D will be the same.

Below is an example where one route is a subset of other:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyy&waypoint0=geo!50.114590,8.687078&waypoint1=geo!50.107984,8.664676&jsonAttributes=41&mode=fastest;car;&representation=linkPaging


https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyy&waypoint0=geo!50.114590,8.687078&waypoint1=geo!50.110128,8.673639&jsonAttributes=41&mode=fastest;car&representation=linkPaging
```

Both of the requests has the same link data for the intersecting links. Hope you find this useful!

[image]